# Dropdown menu styling so that menu shows on top of bottom elements. CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm doing this dropdown Menu, I need help with the CSS. Currently, my dropdown menu when I click it, is pushing the content under it, I want the dropdown menu when clicked to stay on top of the component under it. I'll send design picture, so everyone can understand what I want. I'll also send code.

HTML Code:

```
      <DocumentCard className={styles.cardContainer}>
        <DocumentCardImage height={120} imageFit={ImageFit.cover} imageSrc={TestImages.documentPreviewTwo} />
        <DocumentCardDetails>
          <div ref={this.myRef} className={styles.container}>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
            >Politicas</button>
              {this.state.open && (
                <div className={styles.menu}>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem impsun</li>
                    <li>Lorem impsun</li>
                    <li>Lorem impsun</li>
                    <li>Lorem impsun</li>
                    <li>Lorem impsun
                      <ul>
                        <li>Lorem impsun</li>
                        <li>Lorem impsun</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}
          </div>
        </DocumentCardDetails>
      </DocumentCard>
```

CSS Code

```
.cardContainer {
    width: 32%;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 35px;

    .container {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;

        button {
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            color: #707070;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.22;  

        }
        .menu {
            border: 1px solid red;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 2;

            > ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;

                > li {
                    padding: 8px 12px;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Image of desired result:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odTfB.png)

Comment: can you please add a fiddle sample.

Comment: What is Fiddle ?

Comment: Fiddle is a virtual environment where you can test you code an share code with other, you can create a minimal demo of your app there, please check the link and share a minimal code sample to reproduce your issue there. Check the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-txoxmz

Comment: Yout menu should be positioned `absolute` if you want it to be above another html element.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez the menu is already positioned absolute

Comment: it's imposible for an  absolute positioned html element to "push" any other element. You may have wrong css or unknow styles overwritten the position. wihtout a working example it's impossible for any of us to help you. Try to make one and edit your question with it. as Akhil said you may use https://jsfiddle.net/